# Notepad++ - Delete Everything Other Than The Specified Strings

Tags: notepad++, regex, string

I have the following strings that I want to keep and delete the rests:
`uicomp-type="example-string"` `uicomp-type='string-example'`

I use the following regex to find those strings:

```
uicomp-type="(.*?)"|uicomp-type='(.*?)'
```

How to select the strings other than those I want to keep or what's the opposite of the regex above?

I mean like `NOT uicomp-type="(.*?)"|uicomp-type='(.*?)'`

**EDIT:**

Example data set:

```
"Div box"    => '<div uicomp-type='div-stndalone' class="ddasset-div-box"></div>',
                                        "HTML Code"  => '<div uicomp-type='div-code' class="ddasset-html-box"></div>',
                                        "Shortcode"  => '<div uicomp-type="shortcode" class="ddasset-shortcode-box"><input uicomp-type="input-shortcode" type="text" name="" value="" class="shortcodepreviewer" placeholder="Insert your shortcode here!"/></div>',
                                        "Features list"      => '<ul uicomp-type="ul" class="adtdd_ul">
                                                        <li uicomp-type="li"><i uicomp-type="icon" class="mif-checkmark"></i> <dx uicomp-type="text" class="dxeditable"> Features item 1</dx></li>
                                                        <li uicomp-type="li"><i uicomp-type="icon" class="mif-checkmark"></i> <dx uicomp-type="text" class="dxeditable"> Features item 2</dx></li>
                                                        <li uicomp-type="li"><i uicomp-type="icon" class="mif-checkmark"></i> <dx uicomp-type="text" class="dxeditable"> Features item 3</dx></li>
                                                        <li uicomp-type="li"><i uicomp-type="icon" class="mif-checkmark"></i> <dx uicomp-type="text" class="dxeditable"> Features item 4</dx></li>
                                                        <li uicomp-type="li"><i uicomp-type="icon" class="mif-checkmark"></i> <dx uicomp-type="text" class="dxeditable"> Features item 5</dx></li>
                                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                                        </ul>',
                                        "Separator"  => '<div uicomp-type="div" class="adt-dd-separator adt-dd-separator-k"><hr uicomp-type="hr-separator"></div>',
                                        "Badges/ ribbon"  => '<div uicomp-type="null" class="dd-ribbon">
                                                            <div uicomp-type="div-ribbon" class="dd-ribbon-inner"><span uicomp-type="text" class="dxeditable">POPULAR</span></div>
                                                            </div>',
```

Comment: Should be possible with a *negative lookaround* `(?!)`, but can't get it to click. The pattern could be shortened to `uicomp-type=["'](.*?)["']` btw.

Comment: I had tried to use `(?!)` and there is no luck!

Comment: I think it can be done, but my regex-fu is weak. `(?!.*uicomp-type=["'].*?["'])` is the closest I've got; but it returns a whole bunch of useless zero-length matches too. Feel like I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: Haven't given up on this- do you have a small set of example data to test on? Might be able to narrow it down.

Comment: adding the example as you requested!

Answer (score 0):

Not pure regex, but a quick macro can copy all instances to a second tab. NP++ macros are awsome, but a couple quirks add a bit of a creativity requirement.

1. <Record>
2. F3 (Find next)
3. Ctrl-X (Can't copy because of a quirk causing the cursor position to reset)
4. Ctrl-2 (Switch to other (empty) tab)
5. Ctrl-End (Again, cursor is lost)
6. Ctrl-V (Paste in new tab)
7. Enter (Add a line for the next one)
8. Ctrl-1 (Move back to document)
9. <Stop>

Then, in the find window, click "Count" which in your example returned 25 instances. So you can "Run a Macro Multiple Times" (25).